# How to Calculate Circumference of Pipe with Specified Pitch

Tags: math, geometry, formula

How to Calculate Circumference [Perimeter] of a Pipe [Cylinder shape] with Specified Pitch?

Actually I want to find the length of thread to wind a pipe.

Is there any formula or formula name I can refer?

[image]

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: I believe that [Math Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for such questions, since they have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: 2 * pi * r * number of threads?

Comment: @Harrison: that'd be a rough estimate but wouldn't include the pitch. r2pi is the "perfect" circumference, obviously, but this wouldn't include any "drift" distance, pitch, to the distance. IOW, the threads wouldn't be "threads" they would be a series of unconnected circles.

Comment: @BobbyDigital.  Good point.  sqrt( (2*pi*r)**2 + pitch**2) ) * number of threads?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths. Better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the perimeter of an ellipse which is rather an ugly thing (see: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html).  Your minor axis is the diameter of the pipe.  The major axis is the hypotenuse of the right triangle formed from 1/2 of your pitch.